# How can I know the address that sent the BTC?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I made a transaction with bitcoind. I sent money from address A to address B.

At the client which holds the address B, when I issue "gettransaction" passing the transaction id, it shows information like the type (which is receive), the address which received, and the amount. But it does not tell where the BTC came from.

How can I know which address sent the BTC?

Side question: If I sent BTC back to this address, will it work like a "devolution"? (Which is my objective here)

Comment: i think its anonymous, isnt that the point?

Comment: Nope, because blockexplorer shows me who sent. Look: http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/tx/ce1ae0da8c653ec366d110e32edab830e9b28c4d2f16c6f3100c260caee6e341

Answer (score 1):

From [Bitcoin stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/how-to-findout-the-sender-of-a-transaction), (pseudo-code)

```
txid = <relevant transaction id>
addresses = []
raw_tx = decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(txid))
for(input in raw_tx['vin']) {
  input_raw_tx = decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(input['txid']))
  addresses.push(input_raw_tx['vout'][input['vout']]['scriptPubKey']['addresses'][0])
}
```

Comment: To add onto this, I just want to say that this will not work for people using coinbase. Coinbase actually has 2 outputs. One which is the real address of the person and one that is coinbase's tx id address. If you send to the tx-id one then the person will never receive it.